# Azure DevOps Multi Stage Pipeline Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/*.zip - How do I fix?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an Azure DevOps Build (yaml) and Release Pipeline (Classic) successfully deploying to Azure.

I am trying to convert these 2 separate steps in a Multi Stage Yaml Pipeline.

On the Azure App Service Deploy task (`AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4`), I am getting the following error:

```
No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/a/*.zip
```

Below is my Multi Stage Yaml Pipeline

```
stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
    - job: 'Build'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'

      variables:
        buildConfiguration: 'Release'

      steps:
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: Restore
        inputs:
          command: restore
          projects: '**/*.csproj'
          vstsFeed: 'dd55642d-8943-411f-8856-9714dd0da8af'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: Build
        inputs:
          projects: '**/*.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: Test
        inputs:
          command: test
          projects: '**/*[Tt]ests/*.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: Publish
        inputs:
          command: publish
          publishWebProjects: false
          projects: '**/Tools.Client.Blazor.ServerApp.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

      - task: PublishSymbols@2
        displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
        inputs:
          SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
          PublishSymbols: false
        continueOnError: true

      - task: CopyFiles@2
        displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\AzureDeploy'
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: AzureDeploy
          TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\AzureDeploy'

      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        
  - stage: Systest
    jobs:
    - job: 'Systest'
      variables:       
        resourceGroupName: '$(appName)-rg-$(environment)'
        location: 'East US'
        appServiceName: '$(appName)-svc-$(environment)'
        appInsightsName: '$(appName)-ins-$(environment)'
        appServicePlanName: '$(appName)-asp-$(environment)'
        appName: 'tools'
        owner: 'Pod'
        environment: 'systest'    

      steps:
      - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
        displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
        inputs:
          azureResourceManagerConnection: 'Dev/Test Connection'
          subscriptionId: ''
          resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupName)'
          location: '$(location)'
          csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzureDeploy/Tools.azureDeploy.json'
          csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzureDeploy/Tools.azureDeploy.parameter.json'
          overrideParameters: '-appServiceName "$(appServiceName)" -appInsightsName "$(appInsightsName)" -appServicePlanName "$(appServicePlanName)" -owner "$(owner)" -environment "$(environment)" -location "$(location)"'

      - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
        displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: $(appServiceName)'
        inputs:
          ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
          azureSubscription: ''
          appType: 'webApp'
          WebAppName: '$(appServiceName)'
          packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip'
```

Any help / suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's 2 stages the second stage doesn't have the file you published in the first stage, you need to download it.

You can use [Pipeline artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) instead of build artifacts.

> Pipeline artifacts provide a way to share files between stages in a
> pipeline or between different pipelines. They are typically the output
> of a build process that needs to be consumed by another job or be
> deployed. Artifacts are associated with the run they were produced in
> and remain available after the run has completed.

To publish (upload) an artifact for the current run:

```
steps:
- publish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
  artifact: drop
```

And in the second stage, you download the artifact:

```
steps:
- download: current
  artifact: drop
```

You can also achieve it with [build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#how-do-i-publish-artifacts) and download with `DownloadBuildArtifacts@0` task.

Comment: I got this to work using your advice.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score -3):

During Publish it will not work like this. Instead of using path "/home/vsts/work/1/a/*.zip", this path can be used "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Releasepipelinename/drop/*.zip"

Comment: It is strongly recommend to avoid using hard coded directories.  It is best practice to use the provided variables/tasks.  This approach assumes that the artifact will be named the default drop folder name.